# RegEx | Komodo Edit - Remove duplicate search strings

Tags: regex, duplicates, komodo

Note that this has been asked alot before but there was no answer which worked properly. Better if you try it yourself with the provided example.

The wanted RegEx is to remove duplicate strings using Komodo Edit Replace tool.

Example:
The following text(Note: with , i mean newline) -

> ALL_1397 ,
>   ALL_1398 ,
>   A_1000 ,
>   A_1100 ,
>   ALL_1397 ,
>   A_1397 ,
>   A_1100 ,

When searching for ALL_*(Matches any character) and replacing should result in -

> ALL_1397 ,
>   ALL_1398 ,
>   A_1000 ,
>   A_1100 ,
>    ,
>   A_1397 ,
>   A_1100 ,

Also it should not require replacing each string alone. Replace All must work.

Comment: What can be after `ALL`? Digit only? Though I don't think it is possible to remove the duplicates that appears after the first instance, if the string to search for can be flexible.

Comment: You need to have a limit on the character set. Otherwise, it is not possible to even determine the token to compare against.

Comment: How about [|a-z](characters | and a-z)?

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
(A[L]?[L]?_[^\s]*)(.*)(\1)
```

Replace:

```
\01\02
```